# Amazon MWS : Get comments of orders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am working on getting all orders from amazon and displaying them on my site.

I just want to get the user's comments that are placed by customers against their order.

I was looking at the Amazon MWS documentation, but didn't find anything.   I also tried to search it on google but nothing was found.

Is it possible to get comments on orders?

If so, then how?

Comment: did you manage to do this?

Comment: @coder771 At that time, i wasn't able to do this. May be now there is something that can help.

Comment: I still cannot find an api to work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about [Amazon's Buyer-Seller Messaging Service](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200441880). I've looked around and there does not seem any API to access that information. But you can relay those mails to a regular email client (which might be integrated into your web app through POP3 or IMAP). Your responses (sent through SMTP) will appear in Seller Central just like manually entered messages.

Comment: do you know if this is possible now. not sure how reply manager and zendesk channel reply are doing it

Comment: @coder771 I haven't seen any new API regarding this, so your options still are POP/IMAP and SMTP, I'm afraid. ReplyManager has a page stating that you need to set up POP and SMTP ( https://www.replymanager.com/features/administrate ), same is true for Zendesk. While Zendesk does require MWS authentication, it *also* needs an email configuration ( https://www.channelreply.com/zendesk-app/setup-instructions )

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no MWS API for fetching buyer comments for your orders.

We have submitted a request in the past and I recommend that [you do so](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html) as well. Then just keep an eye on the [MWS site](https://developer.amazonservices.com/).

There is however a report type of `_GET_SELLER_FEEDBACK_DATA_` which will give you:

> Tab-delimited flat file that returns negative and neutral feedback (one to
>   three stars) from buyers who rated your seller performance. For all sellers.

Not exactly what you're looking for but it's a start.